# Set WPF VisualStyle in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I'm trying to indent items on a WPF navBar. I can do this in XAML using resources and setting the `visualstyle` to the appropriate style

```
<dx:DXWindow.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="nestedNavBarItemL1" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="nestedNavBarItemL2" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</dx:DXWindow.Resources>

.
.
<dxnb:NavBarItem Content="Source Group"
       ImageSource="Images/Icons/Group.png" 
       VisualStyle="{StaticResource nestedNavBarItemL1}"/>
.
.
```

However, this is fine if the controls are already created but I'm building up the controls through code using something similar to

```
NavBarGroup group1 = new NavBarGroup();
group1.Header = eventItems[i].name;
group1.Tag = eventItems[i].id;

for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
{
    NavBarItem item = new NavBarItem();
    item.Content = "Home";
    item.Tag = "Level" + i;
    //item.VisualStyle = ? How do I set VisualStyle="{StaticResource nestedNavBarItemL1}"/>
    group1.Items.Add(item);
}

group1.IsExpanded = false;
navBarControl.Groups.Add(group1);
```

How do I set `VisualStyle="{StaticResource nestedNavBarItemL1}"` in code?

Thank you,
O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have style defined in resources, you could use `FindResource` method to get it and then assign to the relevant property like this (window is where resource defined):

```
Style visualStyle = (Style)window.FindResource("nestedNavBarItemL1");
item.VisualStyle = visualStyle;
```

If you don't you can create it as shown in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29699/WPF-How-to-create-Styles-in-code-and-magical-Conte) codeproject article.

Answer (score 1):

Define the style in app.xaml then you can access it with `Application.Current.Resources["YourDefinedStyle"] as Style` within your application.

ex:

```
item.VisualStyle = Resources["YourStyle"] as Style
```